# Trace flag is running, but not message when deadlock happens

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, scripting, dbcc, automation

> Trace flags are used to temporarily set specific server
>   characteristics or to switch off a particular behavior

More information on the trace flags are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx)

```
DBCC TRACESTATUS
```

this above, is the command that shows all the trace flags that are currently running on my system.

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1) is there any other way to find the list of trace flags that are currently running, other than `DBCC TRACESTATUS`?

2) It can be seen on the picture above the trace flag 1222 is active but I am not receiving any email when a deadlock occurs. What else needs to be done?

Comment: Trace Flag 1222 does not send an email when a deadlock occurs, it logs more information in the Log. http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/

Comment: You must now rely on [extended events trace](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/getting-historical-deadlock-info-using-extended-events/) to capture deadlock information. Actually it will automatically capture. With `T- 1222`, it might miss some deadlock information

Comment: @Shanky I got it here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114387/what-are-the-costs-of-enabling-extended-events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the server wasn’t sending emails is due to this flag not being set:

```
EXEC master..sp_altermessage 1205, 'WITH_LOG', TRUE;
GO
```

Even though it was logging in the event log via the trace flag, this also needs to set in order to trigger the emails.
You can see the table here:

```
select * from master.sys.messages
where text like '%deadlock%'
```